# Need help creating an OUTER JOIN to count spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `vw_Lab_Space` which lists out all of my labs, and has a `Lab_Space_Id` column which is the key, and a `Campus_Name` column, plus a bunch of other columns.

Then in the `vw_Subnets` table, which is a list of every subnet, I've got a foreign key with the same name of `Lab_Space_Id` and a distinct key of `Subnet_Name`.

I'm trying to identify, for every `Campus_Name`, how many labs exist in total, and how many labs are associated to at least one subnet.  Many of the labs will have 0 subnets associated to them...i.e. there is no entry in `vw_Subnets` with a `Lab_Space_Id` for that lab.

So I'm thinking I need some type of `OUTER JOIN` but I just can't come up with the right syntax.

```
Campus_Name | Lab_Space_Id    
--------------------------  
Red         | 1   
Red         | 2   
Green       | 3   
Blue        | 4   
Blue        | 5   


Lab_Space_Id | Subnet_Name  
--------------------------  
1            | A  
3            | B
```

Output would be:

```
Campus | # Labs | # Labs with Subnets  
-------------------------------------
Red    | 2      | 1  
Green  | 1      | 1  
Blue   | 2      | 0
```

Comment: sample data and the expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Sample data, the desired output, and the SQL you've written so far where you're having trouble and *can't come up with the right syntax* would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are overthinking it

```
Select A.Campus_Name 
      ,Labs    = sum(1)
      ,SubNets = count(B.Lab_Space_ID)
 from YourTable1 A
 Left Join YourTable2 B on A.Lab_Space_Id = B.Lab_Space_Id
 Group By A.Campus_Name
```

Returns

```
Campus_Name Labs    SubNets
Blue        2       0
Green       1       1
Red         2       1
```