# Linq to SQL conversion...unable to add second COUNT

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to convert my SQL statement to a Linq statement and I'm not sure how to add the second `COUNT` to it.  This is my SQL statement

```sql
SELECT l.Campus_Name, Labs = COUNT(*), LabsWithSubnets = COUNT(s.Lab_Space_Id)
FROM vw_Lab_Space l
LEFT JOIN vw_Subnet s on l.Lab_Space_Id = s.Lab_Space_Id
GROUP BY l.Campus_Name
ORDER BY 1
```

and this is my LINQ statement so far:

```cs
from l in Vw_Lab_Space
from s in Vw_Subnet
            .Where(s => s.Lab_Space_Id == l.Lab_Space_Id)
            .DefaultIfEmpty()   // <=- triggers the LEFT JOIN
group l by new { l.Campus_Name } into g
orderby g.Key.Campus_Name
select new {
    Campus_Name = g.Key.Campus_Name,
    Labs = g.Count()
}
```

So I have everything but the `LabsWithSubnets` part in there.  I'm just not sure how to add that in as I can't just do an `s.Lab_Space_id.Count()` in the select statement.

If you need table structure and sample data please see [Need help creating an OUTER JOIN to count spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49827083/need-help-creating-an-outer-join-to-count-spaces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your query as a basis, you need the groups to include s so you can count when non-null (I also removed the unnecessary anonymous object around the grouping key):

```
from l in Vw_Lab_Space
from s in Vw_Subnet
            .Where(s => s.Lab_Space_Id == l.Lab_Space_Id)
            .DefaultIfEmpty()   // <=- triggers the LEFT JOIN
group new { l, s } by l.Campus_Name into g
orderby g.Key
select new {
    Campus_Name = g.Key,
    Labs = g.Count(),
    LabsWithSubnets = g.Count(ls => ls.s != null)
}
```

However, rather than translate the SQL, I would probably take advantage of LINQ's group join to handle the query slightly differently:

```
var ans = from l in Vw_Lab_Space
          join s in Vw_Subnet on l.Lab_Space_Id equals s.Lab_Space_Id into sj
          group new { l, sj } by ls.Campus_Name into lsjg
          select new {
              Campus_Name = lsjg.Key,
              NumLabs = lsjg.Count(),
              LabsWithSubnets = lsjg.Sum(lsj => lsj.sj.Count())
          };
```

PS Even in your query, I would use `join`...`from`...`DefaultIfEmpty` rather than `from`...`from`...`where` but depending on your database engine, may not matter.

Comment: Thank you.  When I do the `into sj` I see to lose the ability to add `WHERE` conditions.  Is that still possible?  For example, I want to do `where l.Business_Unit <> "xyz"`

Comment: Place the where between the `from` and the `join` if it is on `l`.

Comment: Thanks.  Eventually I'm going to figure linq out!